# Cannot see Standard logs in Eclipse console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse

When I run a Spring Java program in eclipse it only show the output in console, and not the logs with timestamp.
I want something like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXwdI.png)

I tried to do changes in the Run/Debug -> console but still didn't find the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.